# What is Perl's "standard string comparison order"?

Tags: perl, unicode, sorting, collation

This is really a double question, my two end goals having answers to:

- What is the standard string comparison order, in terms of the mechanics?
- What's a better name for that so I can update the docs?

Perl's documentation for [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) says that without a block, `sort` uses "standard string comparison order". But what is that order? There should be a better name for it. For this question, I specifically mean the situation where [locale](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html) is not in effect, since that defines its own order.

In years past, we normally called the standard sort order "ASCIIbetically". It's in [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001322/) and many other books. However, that term is dated. Perl has been Unicode-aware since 5.6. Talking about ASCII is old school. Since Perl is also Unicode-aware, it knows about character strings. In *sv.c*, `Perl_sv_cmp` knows about `locale`, `bytes`, and UTF-8. The first two are easy. But I'm not confident about the third.

```
/*
=for apidoc sv_cmp

Compares the strings in two SVs.  Returns -1, 0, or 1 indicating whether the
string in C<sv1> is less than, equal to, or greater than the string in
C<sv2>. Is UTF-8 and 'use bytes' aware, handles get magic, and will
coerce its args to strings if necessary.  See also C<sv_cmp_locale>.

=cut
*/
```

When Perl sorts using UTF-8, what is it really sorting? The bytes the string encodes to, the characters it represents (including marks maybe?), or something else? I think this is the relevant line in *sv.c* (line 6698 for commit 7844ec1):

```
 pv1 = tpv = (char*)bytes_to_utf8((const U8*)pv1, &cur1);
```

If I'm reading that right (using my rusty C), `pv1` is coerced to octets, turned into UTF-8, then coerced to characters (in the C sense). I think that means it's sorting by the UTF-8 encoding (i.e. the actual bytes that UTF-8 uses to represent a code point). Another way to say that is that it doesn't sort on graphemes. I think I've almost convinced myself I'm reading this right, but some of you know way more about this than I do.

From that, the next interesting line is 6708:

```
 const I32 retval = memcmp((const void*)pv1, (const void*)pv2, cur1 < cur2 ? cur1 : cur2);
```

To me that looks like once it has `pv1` and `pv2`, which were coerced to `char *`, now are just compared byte-by-byte because they are coerced to `void *`. Is that what happens with `memcmp`, which looks like it's just comparing bits based on the various docs I've read so far? Again, I'm wondering what I'm missing in the trip from bytes->utf8->char->bytes, like maybe a Unicode normalization step. Checking out `Perl_bytes_to_utf8` in *utf8.c* didn't help me answer that question.

As a side note, I'm wondering if this is the same thing as the [Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)? If it is, why does [Unicode::Collate](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Unicode-Collate) exist? From the looks of it, I don't think Perl's `sort` handles canonical equivalence.

Comment: There's an easy way to see if they sort UTF-8 sequences byte by byte: if you do so, you get A < B < ... < Z < a < b < ...  Is that what you observe in your environment?

Comment: (Replying to myself)  Yes, that's what I observe when all locales are set to "C".  Seems to confirm your analysis of the source code.

Comment: Well, the sequence you want to observe is dependent on what you think the sequence already should be, which is why there is a Unicode Collation Algorithm. :)

Comment: That's not what I want to observe, that's what I do observe.  This sorting order is never linguistically relevant, even for English (and has been so for decades, long before Unicode).  I suppose the only reason why it even exists is to have a total order over all character strings, at very little overhead.

That being said, the real question behind your question is the default behaviour of `cmp`, since that's what determines the sort order of strings.

Comment: I'd ask Marcus Kuhn: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html

Comment: @Kinopiko: thanks for the link. That looks useful even if I don't get an answer. :)

Comment: As an unrelated note, the "standard string order" should be a natural sort (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001018.html) rather than the ASCIIbetical (or UTFbetical?) sort it (likely) does.

Comment: Well, "natural" sorting order is what locale is for, since languages disagree on the order of characters. sort() has never been about natural order, which shows decades of legacy and decisions that seemed right in the 50s and 60s. Advanced tech aliens are probably never going to visit a stupid backwater planet like this one. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UTF-8 has the property that sorting a UTF-8 string byte-by-byte according to the byte value gives the same ordering as sorting it codepoint-by-codepoint according to the codepoint number. That is, I know without looking that the UTF-8 representation of U+2345 is lexicographically after the UTF-8 representation of U+1234.

As for normalization, the Perl core doesn't know anything about it; to get accurate sorting and comparison among the different forms you would want to run all of your strings through [Unicode::Normalize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Normalize) and convert them all to the same normalization form. I can't comment on which is best for any given purpose, mostly because I have no clue.

Also, sorting and `cmp` are affected by the `locale` pragma if it's in use; it uses the POSIX collation order. Using `use locale`, an 8-bit locale, and unicode all together is a recipe for disaster, but using `use locale`, a UTF-8 locale, and unicode *should* work usefully. I can't say I've tried it. There's an awful lot of info in [perllocale](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perllocale) and [perlunicode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlunicode) anyway.

Comment: Okay, I think that's the sort of confirmation I needed. I thought that was how it worked but I wasn't sure. Come to a meeting sometime so I can buy you a beer. :)

Comment: I've been meaning to get to some meetings, but my schedule usually has me working until 7PM or later, so I usually have to miss them. I'll try to work something out.

Comment: That's a really interesting fact I didn't know. Seems like a smart design decision to me! (Obvious in hindsight, but hey, most smart decisions are.)

Comment: @briandfoy I would never call codepoint ordering *lexicographic*, if I were you.

Answer (score 5):

I can't answer the whole question, so let me hone in on one part:

```
    const I32 retval = memcmp((const void*)pv1, (const void*)pv2, cur1 < cur2 ? cur1 : cur2);
```

> ... looks like once it has `pv1` and `pv2`, which were coerced to `char *`, now are just compared byte-by-byte because they are coerced to `void *`. Is that what happens with `memcmp`

Pretty much.  The main differences differences between `memcmp` and `strcmp` are:

1. `strcmp` will stop once it sees a `NULL` (i.e., `'\0'`), and Perl allows scalars to have embedded `NULL`s
2. `memcmp` often runs just a little bit faster than `strcmp`

But aside from that you're going to get the same results.